# MSVC (std:c++17) Optional always returning a value

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, raytracing, stdoptional

I'm writing some intersection code for a Ray tracer. After calculating some intersection logic for a sphere, I want to return an optional to determine if there was an intersection or not. Instead of returning an "invalid" value for distance, I want to use C++'s `std::optional` class. The only issue is that it seems to always return `true` for `has_value()`:

```
std::optional<Intersection> Sphere::ray_intersection(Ray ray)
    // Calculate Intersection Logic
    // ...
    if (distance_to_intersection < 0) {
        return std::nullopt;
    } else {
        return Intersection(ray, distance_to_intersection);
    }
}
```

After returning, I check using the following code:

```
if (sphere.ray_intersection(ray).has_value()) {
    return shade(sphere, intersection);
} else {
    return background_color;
}
```

I know the actual intersection logic works correctly, because when I replace `return std::nullopt;` with `return Intersection(ray, -1);` (an invalid distance) and then simply check if the distance is equal to `-1` in the previous `if` check, it behaves as expected.

I've also tried returning a simple `{}` to no avail.

I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, and I have tried both the C++17 and C++20 compilers, and neither will behave as I'm expecting.

Is there a specific way that `std::optional` operates that I'm not aware of?

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://onlinegdb.com/qCh3xKVM-), so it is probably a bug in MSVC. That being said, you probably want to pass the found `Intersection` to `shade()`, which means you need to save the `optional` to a variable first, eg: `auto intersection = sphere.ray_intersection(ray); if (intersection.has_value()) { return shade(sphere, intersection.value()); } else { ... }`

Comment: Try to find and post a [minimal reproducible example(MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). An MRE not only helps others to understand your problem, but also usually leads you to find the real problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more code I could have provided. It covers everything that could be going wrong. I believe it maybe a bug in the MSVC. I attempted to print the contents of `std::nullopt` after returning, and although it would pass the `has_value()` check, all properties would be printed as `NaN`.

Comment: @JoshMcCord See how much code [I had to add](https://onlinegdb.com/qCh3xKVM-) to your example just to compile and run it? That is the definition of a [mcve]. In any case, you need to step through the code with a debugger to see exactly what is happening at runtime. The `std::optional` is clearly not being constructed the way you are expecting.

Comment: Does `Intersection` have a constructor that takes a `std::optional` or `std::nullopt_t`?